# Proving discontinuity of a Dirichlet like function

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

> Let $ f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
> x &if  &x\in \mathbb{Q}  & \\ 
> 0&  if&x\not\in \mathbb{Q}
> \end{matrix}\right. $
>
> Prove that $f(x)$ is continuous only at $0$.

Here is what I have:

We must show that for every $\varepsilon>0 $ there is a $\delta>0$ such that if $\left | x-0 \right |<\delta$, $\left | f(x)-f(0) \right |<\varepsilon $.

Let $\varepsilon>0 $ and $\delta=\varepsilon$.

$\left | x-0 \right |=\left | x \right |<\delta$

$\left | f(x)-f(0) \right |=\left | x-0 \right |=\left | x \right |<\delta=\varepsilon$

So $f(x)$ is continuous at $0$.

I have to show now that $f(x)$ is not continuous at $x,y\neq0$

Let $\delta>0$, $ \varepsilon=\left | x-y \right |$

Case 1: if x is rational

The interval $(x-\delta, x+\delta)$ contains an irrational number $y$.

$|x-y|<\delta$

$|f(x)-f(y)|=|x-0|>|x-y|=\varepsilon$

Case 2: if x is not rational

The interval $(x-\delta, x+\delta)$ contains a rational number $y$.

$|x-y|<\delta$

$|f(x)-f(y)|=|0-y|=|y|>|x-y|=\varepsilon$

So $f(x)$ is not continuous at $x,y\neq0$.

Is this correct? Any suggestions? I am kind of reluctant of using an $\varepsilon$ that is a function of two variables. Well is it all right that I chose my $\varepsilon=|x-y|$? Thank you. :)

Comment: You cannot pick $\epsilon$ depending on $y$ that is to be chosen later. However, $\epsilon=\frac12|x|$ should suffice.

Comment: For these type of functions, I think it is much better to choose sequences.

Comment: Thank you for your reply sir. So I can only set for $\varepsilon$ other values that are already fixed? Suppose now that I set $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{2}|x|$ How do I show that $y>\varepsilon$?

Comment: Can the I set the $y$ I will choose in case 2 to be a rational number greater than the $\frac{1}{2}|x|$? That way I will immediately have $y>\varepsilon$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nowhere continuous function limit](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1475703/nowhere-continuous-function-limit)